# How to assign a result to a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typeguards

I'm currently writing an API wrapper/library (class-based) that interacts with a low-code API. One of its functionalities is calling an action on this low-code platform and using the result of that action. The person that's going to use the library knows what action he's going to call on the platform, and so he knows what the type of the result should be.

Example Code with Foo as action

```
interface SpecialObject {
  a: string;
  doSomething(): void;
}

namespace LowCodeAPI {
  export declare function actionCall(x: string): SpecialObject | string;
}

export class Foo<T extends string | SpecialObject> {

  private _result!: T;
  private _name: string;

  constructor(name: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this._name = name;
    this._result = LowCodeAPI.actionCall(this._name);
    return this;
  }

  result(): T {
    return this._result;
  }
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
const Action1: Foo<SpecialObject> = new Foo<SpecialObject>("action_1");
const Action2: Foo<string> = new Foo<string>("action_2");

action_1.result().doSomething();
console.log(action_2.result())
```

But this code can't compile because:

```
 Type 'string | SpecialObject' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string | SpecialObject' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | SpecialObject'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | SpecialObject'.
```

I type guard could be a nice solution, but I can't find out how to write a type guard with a generic type. I think I'm trying to solve this problem the wrong way, but I don't know what the proper way should be :)

Comment: Unrelated to the typing but note that `ActionThatReturnsSpecialObject.execute().result()` will give you `undefined`, since `fetch()` is asynchronous so `._result`will not be populated by the time `.result()` is executed.

Comment: Thanks that's true :) This is just an abstraction of the problem. Do you think I should update this, to make the question more clear?

Comment: Just trying to warn of potential problem.

Comment: To make this a [mre] it probably shouldn't have unrelated problems or issues.  Ideally someone could paste the code, as-is, into a standalone IDE and see your problem without having other ones.  So `SpecialObject` should be defined or replaced with something else.  Same thing with `LowCodeAPI`.  Since this is an abstraction you can make things synchronous instead of asynchronous; there's no reason to distract us with how promises get resolved unless that's part of the question.

Comment: Like, could you change the example to [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wERdyN)?  This has the problem you mention, but wouldn't have the other issues.

Comment: Assuming that works for you, then I have further questions.  How do *you* know that the returned value will be the right type?  Is there something about the `name` that the compiler could use to verify?  If so then could you spell out that logic in the question? If not, then you might as well use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZjYom).  Let me know (and mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: I see you've done the edit but I'm still waiting to hear back about the question in my prior comment.  Let me know when you know. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Updated the example code! Thx for the clarification. 
As for your last question, didn't know that that was possible. But that doens't seem to be clean at all. Is there anyway to write a typeguard for a generic type?

Comment: Your edit uses `Action1` and `action_1` but only one of those is right, right?  "Is there anyway to write a typeguard for a generic type?" I can't answer this unless you answer my question first: "How do you know that the returned value will be the right type? Is there something about the name that the compiler could use to verify? If so then could you spell out that logic in the question?"  Maybe you'd be happy passing in the type guard yourself like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nleaxm)? If so I could write that up as an answer.  Let me know.